# Modify xml file with shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, file, tags

I have a file that contains a lot of XML code and i want to modify a part of that file with a certain value.

Example:

let's suppose I have lots of tags named target and I want to search for a certain name to do the modification.

```
<target name="forest US" description="have more species" >
    <modification.start.yes/>
    <modif.fr.ss type="Animals" color="brown" outputFile="New_type.csv" />
    <modification.end.yes/>
</target>
```

What I want to do is search in my XML file for the tag that has the name of *forest US* change the type from *Animals* to *Plants* for example
and the outputFile from *New_type.csv* to *Old_type.csv*.

I tried with this sed command:

(the command in general)

`sed 's#<target name="forest US" description="have more species">.*#<target name="forest US" description="have more species">SOMETHING</target>#' file.xml`

I'd like to know if there is other approaches, because this one didn't work correctly.

thank you!

Comment: It is a very easy task by using XSLT transformation.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is not meant as spam, it's just a general remark)

It's a typical mistake trying to manipulate special formats (`XML`, `JSON`) using standard commands and tools (`grep`, `sed`, `awk`, ...), but this is a bad habit: you might break the format and make the file unusable.

Better is to look for generally used tools to perform those tasks:

- `jq` for JSON
- [`xmllint` for XML](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement what you need by using XSLT.

The XSLT is using so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

You can use [xsltproc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/xsltproc.htm)  or ***Saxon*** for actual XSLT tranformation.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <target name="forest US" description="have more species">
        <modification.start.yes/>
        <modif.fr.ss type="Animals" color="brown" outputFile="New_type.csv"/>
        <modification.end.yes/>
    </target>
    <target name="desert US" description="have more species">
        <modification.start.yes/>
        <modif.fr.ss type="Animals" color="brown" outputFile="New_type.csv"/>
        <modification.end.yes/>
    </target>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="target[@name='forest US']/modif.fr.ss">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">Plants</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@color"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="outputFile">Old_type.csv</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<root>
  <target name="forest US" description="have more species">
    <modification.start.yes/>
    <modif.fr.ss type="Plants" color="brown" outputFile="Old_type.csv"/>
    <modification.end.yes/>
  </target>
  <target name="desert US" description="have more species">
    <modification.start.yes/>
    <modif.fr.ss type="Animals" color="brown" outputFile="New_type.csv"/>
    <modification.end.yes/>
  </target>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already explained, it would be much better to use a dedicated XML tool. Just in case there is really no other possibility than `sed` (unlikely), and if your XML is very, very simple (as what you show):

```
sed '/<target name="forest US" description="have more species" >/,/<\/target>/{
  s#type="Animals"#type="Plants"#;
  s#outputFile="New_type.csv"#outputFile="Old_type.csv"#;
}' file.xml
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response, I have a small question: what if I don't know what value i have in type, and I want to change it to Plants, what I mean is that I don't know previously that I have Animals in type, and type should have the value of plants afterwords?

Comment: Replace `Animals` by `[^"]*` which means: any character except `"`, zero or more time (but as much as possible). If you edit your question to reflect this change I'll also edit my answer.